# Firebase timestamp

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
 let ref = DataBase.child("post").child(post.userUid).child("postDate")
    ref.observe(.value, with: {
        snap in
        let value = snap.value as? NSDictionary
        let date = value?["postDate"] as? String ?? ""
        print("DATE: \(date)")
    })
```

How can I turn the date into sec, min, hours and days? lets say an image as been post 30 sec from now. I want to print (30 sec ago), if it's 2 hours I want to print ( 2 hours ago), if it's 1 day (1 day ago)
Can't find any info on the internet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Date which has a few timeIntervalSinceDate methods that calculate the time from a given date. You would still need to convert the string to a date so you would still need dateFromString from DateFormatter.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/date

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for you answer but what I want is : lets say an image as been post 30 sec from now. I want to print (30 sec ago), if it's 2 hours I want to print ( 2 hours ago), if it's 1 day (1 day ago). Thank you